# pasting lines in notepad++ with slight variation in them using regex

Tags: regex, notepad++, text-editor

I have a query to be run in SQL:
`select empid, empname from emp_00` 
But the issue is that details of employee are in a hundred tables whose names range from emp_00 to emp_99 ie. emp_00 , emp_01, emp_02 .... emp_99.

I want to get information of all employees using query:

```
select empid, empname from emp_00 union
select empid, empname from emp_01 union
select empid, empname from emp_02 union
.
.
.
select empid, empname from emp_99
```

Is there any method make this entire query in notepad++ (maybe using regex), as my original query is somewhat bigger than this and it would be tough to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tricky part with regex would be to zero-pad the employee Ids.
Thankfully it's a really short python code:

```
nb_employee = 999
padding_len = len(str(nb_employee))
for i in range(nb_employee + 1):
    print(f"select empid, empname from emp_%s union"%(str(i).zfill(padding_len)))
```

Does it do what you expected?

Edit: if you don't have python you can run it online there: https://www.online-python.com/8q0ksUagwb

Comment: Thank you very much @Tranbi. This method instantly solved my problem.